# My application becomes very slow

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have approximately 15 properties of every control binding to the database.

My application needs to provide properties like HorizontalAlignment, VerticalAlignment, Margin, Background, Foreground,........... that can be set by clients. So, I have created a table in database to save the values of those properties when clients set them. I retrieve the values of that properties in ViewModel's Constructor.

But when my application runs it takes 7-8 minutes to load before it starts completely.

Here is a small sample of my code:

**XAML**

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="{Binding HaemogramRowHaemoglobinTest}" Grid.Column="{Binding HaemogramColumnHaemoglobinTest}"
           Grid.RowSpan="{Binding HaemogramRowSpanHaemoglobinTest}" Grid.ColumnSpan="{Binding HaemogramColumnSpanHaemoglobinTest}"
           Text="{Binding HaemogramTextHaemoglobinTest}" 
           Visibility="{Binding HaemogramVisibilityHaemoglobinTest, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
           Background="{Binding HaemogramBackgroundHaemoglobinTest, Converter={StaticResource colorNameToSolidColorBrushConverter}}" 
           Foreground="{Binding HaemogramForegroundHaemoglobinTest, Converter={StaticResource colorNameToSolidColorBrushConverter}}"
           FontFamily="{Binding HaemogramFontNameHaemoglobinTest, Converter={StaticResource stringToFontFamilyConverter}}" 
           FontSize="{Binding HaemogramFontSizeHaemoglobinTest}"
           FontWeight="{Binding HaemogramFontBoldHaemoglobinTest, Converter={StaticResource booleanToBoldConverter}}" 
           FontStyle="{Binding HaemogramFontItalicsHaemoglobinTest, Converter={StaticResource booleanToItalicsConverter}}"
           TextDecorations="{Binding HaemogramFontUnderlineHaemoglobinTest, Converter={StaticResource booleanToUnderlineConverter}}"
           HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HaemogramHorizontalAlignmentHaemoglobinTest, Converter={StaticResource intToHorizontalAlignmentConverter}}" 
           VerticalAlignment="{Binding HaemogramVerticalAlignmentHaemoglobinTest, Converter={StaticResource intToVerticalAlignmentConverter}}"
           Margin="{Binding HaemogramMarginHaemoglobinTest}" >
```

**ViewModel**

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    using (Lab_Lite_Entities db = new Lab_Lite_Entities())
    {
        HaemogramRowTest = db.Designs.Where(d => d.MasterPage.Value == "Haemogram Report" && d.FieldName == "Test").Select(d => d.ParentGridRow).FirstOrDefault();
        HaemogramColumnTest = db.Designs.Where(d => d.MasterPage.Value == "Haemogram Report" && d.FieldName == "Test").Select(d => d.ParentGridColumn).FirstOrDefault();
        HaemogramRowSpanTest = db.Designs.Where(d => d.MasterPage.Value == "Haemogram Report" && d.FieldName == "Test").Select(d => d.ParentGridRowSpan).FirstOrDefault();
        HaemogramColumnSpanTest = db.Designs.Where(d => d.MasterPage.Value == "Haemogram Report" && d.FieldName == "Test").Select(d => d.ParentGridColumnSpan).FirstOrDefault();
        HaemogramTextTest = db.Designs.Where(d => d.MasterPage.Value == "Haemogram Report" && d.FieldName == "Test").Select(d => d.TextField).FirstOrDefault();
        HaemogramVisibilityTest = db.Designs.Where(d => d.MasterPage.Value == "Haemogram Report" && d.FieldName == "Test").Select(d => d.Visibility).FirstOrDefault();
        HaemogramBackgroundTest = db.Designs.Where(d => d.MasterPage.Value == "Haemogram Report" && d.FieldName == "Test").Select(d => d.BackgoundColour).FirstOrDefault();
        HaemogramForegroundTest = db.Designs.Where(d => d.MasterPage.Value == "Haemogram Report" && d.FieldName == "Test").Select(d => d.TextColour).FirstOrDefault();
        HaemogramFontNameTest = db.Designs.Where(d => d.MasterPage.Value == "Haemogram Report" && d.FieldName == "Test").Select(d => d.FontName).FirstOrDefault();
        HaemogramFontSizeTest = db.Designs.Where(d => d.MasterPage.Value == "Haemogram Report" && d.FieldName == "Test").Select(d => d.FontSize).FirstOrDefault();
        HaemogramFontBoldTest = db.Designs.Where(d => d.MasterPage.Value == "Haemogram Report" && d.FieldName == "Test").Select(d => d.Bold).FirstOrDefault();
        HaemogramFontItalicsTest = db.Designs.Where(d => d.MasterPage.Value == "Haemogram Report" && d.FieldName == "Test").Select(d => d.Italics).FirstOrDefault();
        HaemogramFontUnderlineTest = db.Designs.Where(d => d.MasterPage.Value == "Haemogram Report" && d.FieldName == "Test").Select(d => d.Underline).FirstOrDefault();
        HaemogramHorizontalAlignmentTest = db.Designs.Where(d => d.MasterPage.Value == "Haemogram Report" && d.FieldName == "Test").Select(d => d.HorizontalAlignment).FirstOrDefault();
        HaemogramVerticalAlignmentTest = db.Designs.Where(d => d.MasterPage.Value == "Haemogram Report" && d.FieldName == "Test").Select(d => d.VerticalAlignment).FirstOrDefault();
        double? HaemogramMarginLeftTest = db.Designs.Where(d => d.MasterPage.Value == "Haemogram Report" && d.FieldName == "Test").Select(d => d.MarginLeft).FirstOrDefault();
        double? HaemogramMarginTopTest = db.Designs.Where(d => d.MasterPage.Value == "Haemogram Report" && d.FieldName == "Test").Select(d => d.MarginTop).FirstOrDefault();
        double? HaemogramMarginRightTest = db.Designs.Where(d => d.MasterPage.Value == "Haemogram Report" && d.FieldName == "Test").Select(d => d.MarginRight).FirstOrDefault();
        double? HaemogramMarginBottomTest = db.Designs.Where(d => d.MasterPage.Value == "Haemogram Report" && d.FieldName == "Test").Select(d => d.MarginBottom).FirstOrDefault();
        HaemogramMarginTest = new Thickness((double)HaemogramMarginLeftTest, (double)HaemogramMarginTopTest, (double)HaemogramMarginRightTest, (double)HaemogramMarginBottomTest);
    }
}

...

...

And the properties are declared with implementation of OnPropertyChanged.
```

Now the problem here is there are more than 1500 properties whose value comes from the Constructor of ViewModel. Due to that my application becomes very slow.

Is there any way to make application somewhat faster?

Comment: Is the number of rows in `Designs` significantly greater than 1500?  If so, what distinguishes those rows from the ones you consume (other than their property name)?

Comment: @KirkWoll Nope, number of rows in Designs at the moment is near about 70 only. And it will reach to 600 maximum at the end of the development. But each row has 18 fields and each field is bound to a property.

Comment: In that case, you can just load all 70 into memory and do what you want with them.  The performance should be extremely fast if you do that.

Comment: I will try that and let you know the results.

Comment: Besides the problem in topic I think it is waste of database space to save user window preferences. It's not sensitive data so that should be set in settings file, which will be also faster. If your aim is to provide same environment between application instances/devices then you should also use some kind of blob storage to retrieve settings file only.

Comment: @MichaelCwienczek Can you show me some example of blob storage because I have heard this word first time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to have a lot of redundant database selects. Rewriting the block a little should improve performance. I'm not sure about your datatypes so I used default `null` for your fields below;

```cs
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    using (Lab_Lite_Entities db = new Lab_Lite_Entities())
    {
        // A single select from the database
        var design = db.Designs.FirstOrDefault(
            d => d.MasterPage.Value == "Haemogram Report" && 
                 d.FieldName == "Test");

        // Build your members from that select
        HaemogramRowTest    = design != null ? design.ParentGridRow : null;
        HaemogramColumnTest = design != null ? design.ParentGridColumn : null;
        ...
```

Comment: @Khushi If your variables already have a default value, you can simplify things by just returning if `design == null` before assigning anything instead of doing the conditional assignment. Then you can just do `HaemogramRowTest = design.ParentGridRow;` etc.